# Move semantics, standard collections, and construction time address

Tags: c++, c++11, directx, move, standard-library

Of course I would like to know some magic fix to this but I am open to restructuring.

So I have a class `DeviceDependent`, with the following constructor

```
DeviceDependent(Device& device);
```

which stores a reference to the device. The device can change state, which will necessitate a change in all `DeviceDependent` instances dependent on that device. (You guessed it this is my paltry attempt to ride the directX beast)

To handle this I have the functions `DeviceDependent::createDeviceResources()`, `DeviceDependent::onDeviceLost()`.

I planned to register each `DeviceDependent`instance to the device specified in the `DeviceDependent` constructor. The Device would keep a `std::vector<DeviceDependent*>` of all `DeviceDependent` instances so registered. It would then iterate through that vector and called the above functions when appropriate.

This seemed simple enough, but what I especially liked about it was that I could have a `std::vector<DeviceDependent (or child)>` somewhere else in the code and iterate over them quickly. For instance I have a class `Renderable` which as the name suggest represents a renderable object, I need to iterate over this once a frame at least and because of this I did not want the objects to be scattered throughout memory.

Down to business, here is the problem:

When I create the solid objects I relied on move semantics. This was purely by instinct I did not consider copying large objects like these to add them to the `std::vector<DeviceDependent (or child)>` collection. (and still abhor the idea)

However, with move semantics (and I have tested this for those who don't believe it) the address of the object changes. What's more it changes after the default constructor is called. That means my code inside the constructor of `DeviceDependant` calling `device.registerDeviceDependent(this)` compiles and runs fine, but the device accumulates a list of pointers which are invalidated as soon as the object is moved into the vector.

I want to know if there is someway I can stick to this plan and make it work.

Things I thought of:

1. Making the 'real' vector a collection of shared pointers, no issue copying. The object presumably will not change address. I don't like this plan because I am afraid that leaving things out on the heap will harm iteration performance.
2. Calling register after the object has been moved, it's what I'm doing provisionally but I don't like it because I feel the constructor is the proper place to do this. There
   should not exist an instance of `DeviceDependent` that is not on some device's manifest.
3. Writing my own move constructor or move assignment functions. This way I could remove the old address from the device and change it to the new one. I don't want to do this because I don't want to keep updating it as the class evolves.

Comment: Is `DeviceDependent` a kind of device? If so, you should only have `Device` and that should own multiple `Device`s (that depend on this `Device`).

Comment: "What's more it changes after the default constructor is called." -- this does not make *any* sense at all. Once an object has been created, the address is its identity - it can only change when you're talking about a different object.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer since I'm not sure this is what you're asking for, but [here's one way to do what I think you're asking](http://ideone.com/GJIjdH)

Comment: @AnotherTest No, DeviceDependent is not a type of Device. Device manages several COM interfaces via Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr (wrapping a wrapper :p). DeviceDependent uses these interfaces but should not have one for each, as would occur if it was a derived class. Imagine ToolChest, all the workers in the garage depend on the tools to function but they are not themselves a type of ToolChest. (at least that is how I am thinking about it)

Comment: @TomKnapen I hope that didn't take you too long. Yes that would work I think because of

`DeviceDependant::DeviceDependant(DeviceDependant && dep)
: device_(nullptr) {
        dep.unregister_self();
        std::swap(device_, dep.device_);
        register_self();
}`

That's the move constructor right, which means move semantics would work and the pointer in Device would update. If you think that's the best option it probably is, I simply didn't want to keep updating that function as I change DeviceDependent. One last thing, I won't have to define move constructors for derived classes right?

Comment: @Xeo Well perhaps I am just using the wrong terminology then. I am using emplace_back for the vector of solid objects. This does cause 'this' in the constructor explicitly called to be different than the 'this' of the solid object in the vector.

This would be easily understood if the plain old copy constructor was being called but it's not. From what I've read emplace_back is using move semantics which is apparently superior to flat out copying.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with move constructors. The issue is std::vector. When you add a new item to that vector, it may reallocate its memory, and that will cause all the DeviceDependant objects to be transferred to a new memory block internal to the vector. Then new versions of each item will be constructed, and the old ones deleted. Whether the construction is copy-construction or move-construction is irrelevant; the objects effectively change their address either way.

To make your code correct, DeviceDependant objects need to unregister themselves in their destructor, and register themselves in both copy- and move-constructors. You should do this regardless of what else you decide about storage, if you have not deleted those constructors. Otherwise those constructors, if called, will do the wrong thing.

One approach not on your list would be to prevent the vector reallocating by calling reserve() with the maximum number of items you will store. This is only practical if you know a reasonable upper-bound to the number of DeviceDependant objects. However, you may find that reserving an estimate, while not eliminating the vector reallocations entirely, makes it rare enough that the cost of un-registering and re-registering becomes insignificant.

It sounds like your goal is getting cache-coherency for the DeviceDependants. You might find that using a std::deque as main storage avoids the re-allocations while still giving enough cache-coherency. Or you could gain cache-coherency by writing a custom allocator or operator new().

As an aside, it sounds like your design is being driven by performance costs that you are only guessing at. If you actually measure it, you might find that using std::vector> is fine, and doesn't significantly the time it takes to iterate over them. (Note you don't need shared pointers here, since the vector is the only owner, so you can avoid the overheads of reference-counting.)

Comment: I think what you're saying is that I cannot and should not shrink from writing all the constructors regardless of whether I am planning to use them explicitly.

I am 'guessing' about the performance issues but it's an educated guess. I know some of the children of DeviceDependnent will be quite large. I know there are going to be thousands of them. I know that I will have to iterate through them many times a second.

I know as a rule that you should not optimize before you have profiled the whole thing but I don't think you should run headlong into inefficiency either.